# Shadow Root for Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, shadow-root

Can someone please help me with the following - I am trying to perform drag and drop for an element. Below is my code in Python and below that I've included the HTML. My code for some reason isn't working below and Im getting the error "selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator" Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Python:

```
# Locate shadow root selector for QuickMark Types
host1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'tii-qm-side-panel')))
root1 = host1.shadow_root
# Get the target element inside the shadow root
awk_quickmark = root1.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sc5403"]')
assert 'Awk.' in awk_quickmark.text

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(awk_quickmark, 504, 284).perform()
```

HTML:

[!HTML(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ4EP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ4EP.png)

Added screenshot of the error below:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEWhA.png)

Comment: Executing which line are you getting exception?

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the main post

Comment: I realised that there was only one shadow root I had to access - not two. I changed that however the error still persists. For some reason it isn't picking up the xpath for the button